# Python Script to SSH into Windows 10 fails due to '\x1b' escape sequences in cmd prompt output after successful connection

Tags: python, windows, ssh, cmd

I am trying to write a python script to SSH into my Windows10 device and the script looks for '>' character to establish that the connection was successful. The connection itself is successful, but my python script fails.

However, on windows 10, I am seeing '/x1b' ansi escape sequences for color.

My code is as follows:

```
                if re.search('> ', data):
                    cmd = " %s\n" % initialize_command
                    tnh.send(cmd.encode('utf-8'))
                    data = tnh.recv(1024)
                    try:
                        data = data.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                        data = data.decode('utf-8')
                    except UnicodeDecodeError:
                        data = data.decode('iso-8859-1')
                if re.search(r'{0}\s?$'.format(r'(\$|>|#|%)'), data):
                    break
```

My script fails because the script cannot match pattern '\x1b' escape character. So, I tried adding line "data = data.encode('ascii', 'ignore')", but this does not get rid of the asci characters either. Please refer to the snippet below.

> > > data ='J\x1b[25l\x1b[m\x1b[H\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\x1b[H\x1b]0;c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\x07\x1b[?25h\x1b[?25lMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657]\x1b[?25h\x1b[?25l\r\n(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\x1b[52X\x1b[52C\r\nadministrator@VPN-WIN4 C:\Users\Administrator>\x1b[4;47H\x1b]0;Administrator:c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\x07\x1b[?25h'
> > >
> > > data = data.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
> > >
> > > print (data)

b'J\x1b[25l\x1b[m\x1b[H\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\x1b[H\x1b]0;c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\x07\x1b[?25h\x1b[?25lMicrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657]\x1b[?25h\x1b[?25l\r\n(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.\r\n\x1b[52X\x1b[52C\r\nadministrator@VPN-WIN4 C:\Users\Administrator>\x1b[4;47H\x1b]0;Administrator:c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\x07\x1b[?25h'

> > > 

I'm looking for a way my python script establishes that the connection was successful. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `encode`/`decode` won't get rid of the escape character. It *is* ascii.

Comment: The escape sequences in your title and text differ significantly.

Comment: corrected the escape sequence in title